# SigmaJS export graph as GEXF

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

Is it possible to export the graph in SigmaJS as GEXF format? I can import the graph as GEXF, then it will be parsed to JSON, I manipulate it and want to send it back.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one plugin for that on linkurious : https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js/tree/develop/plugins/sigma.exporters.gexf

Cheers.